# Alternative of the macros

Tags: asterisk

Asterisk 16 has the status of macros deprecated.

Which is an alternative of the macros in Asterisk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative:

```
Macro() => Gosub()
MacroExit() => Return()
```

Please note, the name of the context you are going in to Gosub() to, are not prefixed, like it was with Macro(), where it was prefixed with "macro-".

Answer (score 2):

Macro() and MacroExit() are now replaced by Gosub() and Return()

Be carefull when runing Gosub's, as variables will be shared across all of your Gosub.

In case you call a Gosub(context_1,s,1) that's running a same => n,Set(test="foo") to set variable test, this variable will be accessible and set on a Gosub(context_2,s,1) for example